# C - Assign value to pointer at position, is it possible?

Tags: c, pointers, integer, printf, dynamic-memory-allocation

In Visual Studio 2019, I tried to assign value to **int** pointer at specified position, but it doesn't work. Is this possible?

Moreover how I can printf a pointer's value, and not the address?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int *p =(int*)calloc(10,1);
    
    p[0]=1;
    p[1]=0;
    p[2]=1;
    
    printf("%d\n",p);
}
```

Thank

Comment: Unless `sizeof(int)` is 2 on your system (unlikely), this program has undefined behavior.  You have only allocated 10 bytes for an array into which you're trying to store 3 integers.  Regarding printing, using `%d` to display a pointer type is incorrect, as pointer may be larger than an int.  The correct specifier is `%p`.  If instead you're trying to print one of these integers, then you must dereference the pointer to choose one: `printf("%d\n", p[i]);` where `i` is 0, 1 or 2.  But read my first point about memory because you have undefined behavior right now.

Comment: I strongly advise you to revise pointers from whichever resource you're trying to learn C. In my personal opinion, an approach which explains memory in terms of memory itself and not in terms of C's abstractions, is preferable.

Answer (score 1):

1. `calloc(10,1)` allocates `10` single byte items not `10` integers. So (except 8 bits uCs where int is 2 bytes) your allocated memory area is far too short. if you want to allocate space for 10 integers you need to `int *p = calloc(10, sizeof(*p));`
2. `printf("%d", p)` invokes an UB as `p` is the reference (address) stored in the pointer `p`. You need to dereference the pointer to get the integer referenced (pointed) by the `p` pointer `printf("%d\n, *p);`

To print the reference stored in the pointer you need to use the correct format: `printf("%p\n", (void *)p);`.

Answer (score 0):

It works.

To print the value you need to derreference with * or index with [].

```
printf("%d\n",*p); //p[0]
printf("%d\n", p[0]); //p[0]
printf("%d\n",*(p + 1)); //p[1]
printf("%d\n", p[1]); //p[1]
```